# Can't use delete API in PHP

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I've been trying to delete post in my web application, 
but it does not work at all!

it worked before and don't know what happened.

```
$id=1234456789
$result=$facebook->api("/".$id,"DELETE");
```

and the result is below

```
{"error":{"message":"(#100) Invalid parameter","type":"OAuthException"}
```

There is no excution so I can't figure out.
That timeline was posted by exactly same application.

Anybody help?